# Is MySQL cluster over the internet a good idea for online backups?

Tags: mysql

I have a production VPS instance in London, UK (for example). It serves a website with upto 10000 queries per day. I have another instance in Dallas, US whose only duty is to keep **in sync** with the production server by pulling the data.

Is it a good idea (in the first place) to cluster MySQL over the internet? Will the production server degrade in performance if:

1. as long as it's link with the backup server is down
2. if it has to sync a lot with the backup server as it's been offline for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: What you're describing here would be a MySQL master/slave configuration, not MySQL clustering. (MySQL Cluster is an uncommon and quirky variant of MySQL; it's almost certainly not what you want to use.)

> Is it a good idea (in the first place) to <s>cluster</s> **replicate** MySQL over the internet?

Sure. Replication is good stuff.

> Will the <s>production</s> **master** server degrade in performance...

Unless you're severely bottlenecked on I/O, replication should not affect the performance of the master. If the slave (backup) server is expected to be offline for extended periods of time, make sure you're keeping binlogs for a sufficient amount of time.

Comment: So a good internet link is all I need? And that the slave will automatically catch up?

Comment: yes, and if you use the public internet, use VPN or replication SSL.